# Identify this climbing/rambling pink rose

Tags: identification, roses

I have a lovely pink rose on one side of an arch and a white Bobbie James on the other.

I have forgotten the name of the pink rose and would be grateful if anyone could hazard a guess. I don’t know if to treat it as a climber or as a rambler.

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMh2Z.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Rosa Dorothy Perkins https://www.classicroses.co.uk/dorothy-perkins-rambling-rose.html but there are thousands and thousands of newer varieties. Regardless, you can tell very easily whether your rose is a rambler or a climber by its flowering habit - rambling roses flower for about 4-6 weeks, all in one flush, with possibly (but rarely) one or two random flowers later. Climbing roses are repeat flowering, so you don't get one massive display all at once and then no more, you get a number of flowers with more appearing later in similar quantity, provided you deadhead.